# Slow down time Unity3d Mecanim

Tags: c#, time, unity-game-engine

I am trying to slow down and ultimately stop it, i have a script that slows down timeScale however with that my player using mecanim also slows down.

I have created a TimeController.cs
that will allow me to keep track of time by having a alternative deltaTime as the player can use for variable,

```
public class TimeController : MonoBehaviour {

private float oldTimeSinceStart;
public float deltaTime;

void LateUpdate () {
    float timeSinceStart = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
    deltaTime = timeSinceStart - oldTimeSinceStart;
    oldTimeSinceStart = timeSinceStart;

    if (Input.GetButton("BulletTime"))
    {
        if (Time.timeScale > 0.01)
        {
            Time.timeScale -= 0.004f;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (Time.timeScale < 1)
        {
            Time.timeScale += 0.01f;
        }
    }
}
}
```

From this point i thought about using Animator Update to set the mecanim logic driven speed for player speed and animation speed, however i dont seem to be able,
When using Animator.Update(MyTimeController.deltaTime);
It seems to run at variable speed, as if the Animator has a second input somewhere.

is there away around this? can you isolate the timeScale from the player/mecanim and have it  look at another Time class for input variables?

So time slows down for the world but not the player, think clockstoppers!

Comment: @Bart, following my example? :-p

Comment: Ha @Steven, isn't the first, won't be the last. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Acording to Unity Documentation there's this animation speed property in the animator object:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Animator-speed.html

Try using 
`<yourgameobjecthere>.getComponent<Animator>().speed = Time.timescale;` right after you set the time scale.

I'm not sure the animation speed is applied correctly during an animation tho.

Comment: true, but that still doesnt keep the player at normal speed but sets him to timeScale speed, if time is slowed down by 50% the character should stay normal, as if time doesnt slow down for the player but the world around him, think clockstoppers.

Comment: My thought was about, if we reduce timescale to 0.5, character speed should go to 2.0 theoretically, thus 1/0.5 = 2.0, if we decrease timescale to 0.25, character speed goes to 1/0.25 = 4.0. Not sure if this would work in practice tho.

Comment: shoud be fixed. 1/Time.timescale -> Time.timescale

Answer (score 0):

As Felype mentioned, you can use Animator Component, I usually get the Animator component and then use `<animator_object>[<animation_clip_object.name>]`.speed. For speed, value of 1 means normal speed.